# Connecting to local Database from remote web server

Tags: php, odbc, localhost, database-administration

I am trying to connect to my local Database from the webserver but i get

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function odbc_connect() 
             in -/-/-/7001238/web/s/sage2.php on line 15"
```

Any help on how to fix issue.

Here is the code i used to connect.

```
 $odbc['dsn'] = "Sage50";
 $odbc['user'] = "Peach";
 $odbc['pass'] = "XXXX";
 $mysql['host'] = "localhost";
 $mysql['user'] = "root";
 $mysql['pass'] = "";
 $mysql['dbname'] = "sagetest";
 $mysql['idfield'] = "id";
 $debug=true;
 // Step 1: Connect to the source ODBC and target mysql database
 if ($debug) echo "Connect to " . $odbc['dsn'] . ' as ' . $odbc['user'] . "\n";
 $conn = odbc_connect($odbc['dsn'], $odbc['user'], $odbc['pass']);
 if (!$conn) {
    die("Error connecting to the ODBC database: " . odbc_errormsg());
 }
 $myconn = mysql_connect($mysql['host'], $mysql['user'], $mysql['pass']);
 if (!$myconn)
    die("Error connecting to the MySQL database: " . $mysql_error());
 if (!mysql_select_db($mysql['dbname'], $myconn))  die("Error selecting the database: " . mysql_error());
// Step 1.5: loop through each table with steps 2-7
$allTables = odbc_tables($conn);
$tablesArray = array();
while (odbc_fetch_row($allTables)) {
   if (odbc_result($allTables, "TABLE_TYPE") == "TABLE") {
      $tablesArray[] = odbc_result($allTables, "TABLE_NAME");
   }
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: You're mixing `odbc_` with `mysql_` functions, *why?*

Comment: @Fred-ii-, Thanks for the reply. I also going to sync Sage 50 peachtree database with mysql_ thats why your seeing mysql_ functions.

Comment: This might be relevant information http://sagecity.na.sage.com/support_communities/sage50_accounting_us/f/132/t/44819.aspx

Comment: Can you use COM based ODBC from a Unix system?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks!, but it works fine on the localhost. the only problem when trying to access from the remote / the website/. I uploaded the Same PHP code to my remote webserver. Is there anything i have to change on the code to access the local Database from Webserver

Comment: Do you mean you want to access a database on your PC from code running on a Webserver not on your PC i.e. out on the internet?

Comment: @RiggsFolly . Correct and I am working on windows environment - Window 8 64 bit OS

Comment: That is very unlikely to work. The host will almost defintely deny access to external databases. Anyway, the PHP code will be running on a UNIX based webserver that probably was not compiled with ODBC included as its not a unix technology

Comment: I think you are going to have to redesign this syncronisatoin process from scratch

Comment: @RiggsFolly May be But i have to fix this issue and see if it possible to use Local Database for the php code stored on the remote/internet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: This error happens because you don't have the ODBC PHP extension installed.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/odbc.installation.php too.

In debian distros you can solve this with a `apt-get install php5-odbc`, but you can check this also with your hosting provider.

When you see a `Call to undefined function` you always must check the php.net to be sure about the name of function, or the extension is not loaded.

PS 1: I think you're trying to compare/transfer data between two databases, right?

PS 2: Make sure your server can reach the ODBC address. The webserver is not your dev machine, so localhost is not the real localhost ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Correct i am trying to sync two databases. I am using windows do i have to install odbc PHP extension? if so how? it works fine in local Machine, What i am trying to accomplish is to access the local sage 50 Pervasive database using odbc and then sync with MYSQl.